# using appsetting.Development.json for AWS Mock Lambda Test Tool

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, environment-variables, appsettings

Is there any support for `appsetting.Development.json` with AWS Mock Lambda Test Tool. Can I use `appsetting.Development.json` to load the application related setting while debugging lambdas locally. My lambdas are inside `dot net core` library project.

## netcoreapp2.1

Answer (score 4):

This can work even for dot net core class libraries.

```
new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment")}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```