# Loading AppSettings.json in mock lambda test tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda Web API and I'm trying to use code that I've used before to load the `appsettings.json` into memory.

In `appsettings.json` I have this:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "TestValue": "Some value"
    }
}
```

In `StartUp.cs` I have this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

And in `SomeController.cs` I have this:

public class SapController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

```
public SapController(IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> optionsMonitor)
{
    _appSettings = optionsMonitor.CurrentValue;
}
```

The problem is, under the Mock Lambda Test Tool the `_appSettings` properties are all `null`.

I really don't want to load the appsettings using special case code, [as seen in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400355/using-appsetting-development-json-for-aws-mock-lambda-test-tool) and [described here](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-204274c6179b). I really thought it should load as normal. Am I wrong with this opinion?

Is it really necessary to load appsettings under the mock lambda test tool using this code?:

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.Build();
```

Comment: Please post your ``Program.cs`` code

Comment: There isn't one; It's a lambda.

Comment: So where you tell the app to load your AppSettings.json?

Comment: The framework should load it and I acquire it in `StartUp.cs`, see my posted code.

Comment: You just build an ``IConfiguration`` but no use.

Comment: So, what should I do? This is why I'm asking - I don't know.

Comment: maybe this helped https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that for some reason the `appsettings` is not being passed in to my constructors. So my controller now has this in the constructor:

```
public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _appSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Get<AppSettings>();
}
```

The short of it appears to be that I need to acquire the `AppSettings` instance from the `Configuration` instance, rather than having it passed in via IoC.

I still don't know why, but at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking your `appsettings.Development.json` file and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. This will ensure that it will be copied to the same directory as your executable upon build, and your app will find and load it.

You can add the file to your `.gitignore` if you don't want it to be part of your deployment package. Regardless, it will not be read in Production.